# Vaadin Textfields with caption at the left of the box instead of on top?

Tags: vaadin

How do I make my texfield caption to the left of the text box instead of defaulting on top of it?

```
HorizontalLayout hLayout = new HorizontalLayout();
setConent(hLayout);

    TextField tf = new TextField();
    hLayout.addComponent(tf);
```

Comment: can you use a `FormLayout`?

Comment: I have a list of textboxes I need displayed horizontally, not vertically.

Comment: then FormLayouts in HorizontalLayouts?  Label, TextField, ... in HorizontalLayout?  CSS?

Comment: make a form layout for each and every textbox I need? Surely there is an easier way to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either way use `FormLayout` to wrap every `TextBox` as suggested in comments, or you have to alter the css of your `TextBox`. Set style to your `TextBox` to only apply this to those you want.

```
TextBox yourTextBox = new TextBox();
yourTextBox.addStyleName("inline-label");
```

then the css would look like this:

```css
.v-caption-inline-label{
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not do it this way:

```
final FormLayout form = new FormLayout();

form.addComponent(new TextField("Caption line 1"));

final HorizontalLayout formLine2 = new HorizontalLayout();
formLine2.addComponents(new TextField(), new Button(), new Button());
formLine2.setCaption("Caption line 2");
```

The text field in line 1 has the caption left.
The text field in line 2 would have the caption on top due to the horizontal layout container. By moving the caption from the text field to the horizontal layout, the caption will be on the left side again.

Comment: No function for me:  vaadin 8.6